# My IP Address is Wrong?

Tags: networking, ip, ip-address, multiple-computers

I have 2 computers, and I checked the IP address on each computer, by going to [this](https://www.google.ca/search?site=&source=hp&q=my%20ip%20address&oq=my%20ip&gs_l=hp.3.1.0l10.264.1314.0.4020.5.5.0.0.0.0.280.797.1j3j1.5.0....0...1c.1.53.hp..0.5.794.L_d-M10CZKE) site.
On both computers, the IP address is the same?!
Isn't each computer supposed to have a unique ip address?
Google says: a unique string of numbers separated by periods that identifies each computer using the Internet Protocol to communicate over a network.
The two computers are using the same internet.
What's wrong with my IP address?

Comment: The problem with your IP address is that it is too old. The problem you mention happens with version 4 and will be solved when your ISP upgrades to version 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router/gateway will be doing Network Address Translation [NAT] so that any outside IP reporter will only ever see the allocated address of your router.

If you want to know your internal IP Address, then [for Win 7, but similar in others] go to Control Panel > Network & Internet > Network Connections. Right click the connection you see in there, get Status. In the following window hit Details
You will see a line that says similar to `IPv4 Address: 192.168.0.10`

That is your local IP address.

Answer (score 5):

Let me guess, both your systems are behind a router, right?

If so, then there's NOTHING wrong with your IP address(es).

Each computer on your private LAN does have its own IP address, but you only have one *public* Internet IP address, and that's what that site is showing you.

Your router handles the back and forth address translation so that your two devices can share one public (Internet) IP address.

For more info on how NAT routing works, check out these other SU questions:

- [How do IP answer packets reach their destination inside of a private LAN?](https://superuser.com/questions/401802/how-do-ip-answer-packets-reach-their-destination-inside-of-a-private-lan/)
- [How does Router know where to forward packet](https://superuser.com/questions/105838/how-does-router-know-where-to-forward-packet)

Comment: So do I have to go on a different internet?

Comment: "So do I have to go on a different internet?"  Not sure what you mean by this?

Comment: If I go on separate internets, would I get different ips?

Comment: There's only one "Internet".  If you got a second connection to the Internet, then yes it would have its own, separate, public Internet IP. :)

Comment: The ISP could even be using a CGN so getting a second connection from the same ISP might still result in a single public IP address.

Comment: @user2313067 Yes there are a lot of possible options, but none of which really have anything to do with the question at hand; so I tried to keep my example simple.

Comment: @user2313067 - Unlikely considering the ISP cannot assigned the same address twice ( at the same time )

Answer (score 2):

The IP address you see from that site is your public ip. It's the ip of your router not of your computer.

Your router controls traffic between all the computers on your network and the outside world. Within your local network, your computers will have unique ones. From a terminal type `ifconfig` (or `ipconfig` from Windows) to see your local ip.

Comment: So how do you see the computer's ip?

Comment: @Bobthezealot, the computers IP is the one you see on the terminal and determines the address of your computer on your network. The IP the outside world sees is the one you found on the website.